# Show that $GL(n , \mathbb{Z}_{p})$ has no finite dimensional faithful representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups

> How do I show that $G = GL(n , \mathbb{Z}_{p})$ has no finite dimensional faithful representation. $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ is the ring of $p$-adic integers.
>
> If $\rho : G \rightarrow GL(m, \mathbb{C})$ is a finite dimensional representation then $\ker(\rho)$ is open. Can I use this fact in some way?
>
> Is $\{1\}$ an open set in $G$?

Comment: What do you mean with $\ker(\rho)$ is open, is it something that you read as a theorem for  complex representations of $p$-adic groups or what. Also $G$ is not a Lie group in the usual sense (not a real manifold), it is a topological group are you want to restrict to continuous representations.

Comment: I think $G = GL(n ,\mathbb{Z}_{p})$ is totally disconnected and hence $\ker(\rho) =\{ g \in G : \rho(g) = 1 \}\subseteq G$ is open. If I can show $\ker(\rho) \ne \{ 1 \}$, then I can prove the claim, any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, I think I want to restrict to continuous representations. What is the topology of $GL(n, \mathbb{Z}_{p})$ ?

Comment: 'And hence' ? If the kernel is open then it contains a neighborhood of all its elements thus of $1$, that's the definition of open. The topology is the obvious one induced by the $d(A,B)=\sup_{i,j} | A_{ij}-B_{ij}|_p$ metric

Comment: But why is $\ker(\rho) \ne \{1 \}$ ?

Comment: Are singleton points open under this topology?

Comment: What is the definition of $|x-y|_{p}$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}_{p}$?

Comment: The definition is $|p^k u/v|_p = p^{-k}$ for $p^ku/v$ rational, $p\nmid uv$ and $\Bbb{Q}_p$ is the completion of $\Bbb{Q},|.|_p$ and $\Bbb{Z}_p$ is the completion of $\Bbb{Z},|.|_p$. Elements of the latter are limits of sequences of integers that converge $\bmod p^k$ for all $k$.

Comment: So assuming $\ker(\rho)$ Is open, there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\ker(\rho) \supseteq B_{\epsilon}(1)$. Then $B = 1 + p^{k} \delta_{ij} \in B_{\epsilon}(1)$, for $k \geq 0$ such that $p^{-k} < \epsilon$, and $B \ne 1$ so $\ker(\rho) \ne 1$ implying that $\rho$ is not injective. So assuming that $\ker(\rho)$ is open, is this reasoning to conclude $\rho$ is not injective legitimate?